# mysql request retrieve data combined with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables

[image]

I would like to request all persons, where the companyTypeID is for example '2'. How can I query that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   persons
WHERE  CompanyId IN (SELECT CompanyId
                     FROM   company
                     WHERE  CompanyTypeId = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an `INNER JOIN` (left or right joins are functionally similar, the only difference is which side of the equation is honoured). Nested queries / subqueries are [extremely expensive if they become dependent in nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799820/when-to-use-sql-sub-queries-versus-a-standard-join)—even though that's not the scenario in your case—and I do not recommend using them for large tables.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Persons AS t1
LEFT JOIN Company AS t2 ON
    t2.companyTypeID = t1.CompanyID
```

To ensure that you are using an index for joining, you should create indexes on the `companyTypeID` and `CompanyID` columns of each table. Prepend `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to the query above to verify that the indexes are indeed being used.

Answer (score 0):

Perform an SQL join:

Joins are quicker than the subquery, in the other post:

```
SELECT Persons.firstname AS first name
  FROM Persons
  JOIN Company ON company.ID == Persons.CompanyID
 WHERE Company.companyTypeID == 2
```

Although you will need to select all he fields you want, using alias to simplify the names

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL statement JOIN. It's all about mathematical sets!

A Graphic (and superficial) explanation about JOINs statement under mathematical sets approach:

https://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FhhRDO4d.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fprogramming%2Fcomments%2F1xlqeu%2Fsql_joins_explained_xpost_rsql%2F&docid=q4Ank7XVw8j7DM&tbnid=f-L_7a3HkxW_3M%3A&w=1000&h=740&client=ubuntu&bih=878&biw=1745&ved=0ahUKEwj2oaer5evPAhUBFZAKHe4nAdAQMwgdKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8#h=740&w=1000

SQL for your problem(If I got this):

```
SELECT * FROM Persons p LEFT JOIN Company c ON c.ID = p.companyID
                        LEFT JOIN CompanyType ct ON ct.ID = c.companyTypeID
WHERE c.id = 2;
```

Why 'LEFT JOIN'? Checkout the the link about set approach explanation above!

The second 'LEFT JOIN' is just to bring the description of companyType table.

The "*" in statement is didatic! You must not use this in production for the good of performance. Therefore, you must to replace the '*' with all the fields you need. For example, "CONCAT(p.firstname,CONCAT(" ",p.lastname)) as PersonName, c.name CompanyName,..." or something like that. I suppose you're using MySQL

Hope I've helped!